# Keycloak - import password policy

Tags: import, keycloak

I've set up a password policy

[image]

After export everything I've got a json with line:

```
"passwordPolicy": "upperCase(1)"
```

But after import the password policy is no longer visible and export does not contain this line.

**The question is how to write json file, so I can import this policy?**

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do it by calling the Rest Endpoint:

```
PUT https://<KEYCLOAK_IP>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>
```

the json contend `{"realm:"YOUR_REALM", "passwordPolicy":"upperCase(1)"}`

or using [Keycloak Admin CLI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#installing-the-admin-cli), for instance

```
./kcadm.sh update realms/<your_realm> -f example.json
```

with the content of example.json being  `{"realm:"YOUR_REALM", "passwordPolicy":"upperCase(1)"}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution which suits for me, but maybe not for everyone, is to recreate docker with parameter: `keycloak.migration.file` pointing to that exported file. Then the password policy is created correctly.

It looks like import feature is not using every field of exported file.